# Where starts webdriver looking for elements using xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

I'm currently testing a website with Selenium/Webdriver, which displays the names and addresses of people in several boxes. For example, each box contains a First Name field. All these fields have generated IDs, so I can't use them.

My approach is to first find the box and then the element I'm looking for. I use xPath expressions like this, a bit more complex, but for the question it's easier this way

```
WebElement box3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@boxnum,'3')]");
WebElement firstName = box3.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[contains(@field,'firstname')]/input");
```

That there are absolute and relative xPath expressions is also known to me, but apparently I haven't really understood it yet. If I omit the leading point for the search for the fistName element in the xPath, the first name field from the first box is found. However, I assumed that I wouldn't have needed this, since I started the search at "box3". Unfortunately I haven't found a docu that explains this to me in such a way that I understand it. I hope that there is someone here who can explain this.

Comment: Can you post the url or at least the relevant html?

Comment: Sorry, but it is a intranet App

Comment: You need to provide at least relevant html and your expected output else how OP help you

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but why do you need the html? My question is, why does the second xpath expression searches through the whole Dom, instead of just using the part of the page which starts at the already and successfull located element "box3"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.

Given the following code evaluated against https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/bootstrap-dual-list-box-demo.html page which looks like:

[image]

```
driver.get("https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/bootstrap-dual-list-box-demo.html");
WebElement listGroup = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='list-group']"));
List<WebElement> entries = listGroup.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='list-group-item']"));
entries.forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getText()));
```

You will get the next output:

```
bootstrap-duallist
Dapibus ac facilisis in
Morbi leo risus
Porta ac consectetur ac
Vestibulum at eros
Cras justo odio
Dapibus ac facilisis in
Morbi leo risus
Porta ac consectetur ac
Vestibulum at eros
```

as Selenium evaluates the XPath from the document root

And if you modify the code as:

```
driver.get("https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/bootstrap-dual-list-box-demo.html");
WebElement listGroup = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='list-group']"));
List<WebElement> entries = listGroup.findElements(By.xpath(".//li[@class='list-group-item']"));
entries.forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getText()));
```

you will get the values from the first column only.

```
bootstrap-duallist
Dapibus ac facilisis in
Morbi leo risus
Porta ac consectetur ac
Vestibulum at eros
```

as in the 2nd case the XPath expression is applied to the **current node** only

Check out [Selecting Nodes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) chapter:

[image]

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=40044727)

Comment: Thx for this answer, it's verry detailed!

While reading the, on additional question comes into my mind. What would happen, if my second search ist not via xpath. Which part of the DOM would be craweld if i used something like this:

    WebElement firstName = box3.findElement(By.className("xyz"));

Would it use the complete DOM, or just the part which starts at box3?