# Finding elment in Selenium using XPath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

What is the difference between **".//", "//","./" and "/"** in **XPath** while finding element in Selenium? Describe.

Answer (score 3):

XPath Definitions:

```
.// - Find something that is a descendant of the current node
//  - Find something that is anywhere in the DOM
./  - Find a child node of the current node
/   - Find a child of the root of the document
```

However in Selenium .// and // do not follow the XPath specs and mean the same thing, which in this case is find something anywhere in the DOM.

***Edit***

Since this seems to be somewhat controversial, here's some additional information.

Selenium uses wicked good XPath in its JavaScript atoms (See the [Selenium codebase](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/atoms/locators/xpath.js#L44)).

Wicked good XPath while fast, is not a fully compliant XPath implementation and doesn't implement // correctly in all cases hence the assertion above that you should treat both .// and // as an operator to find anything in the DOM (See [this wicked good XPath issue](https://github.com/google/wicked-good-xpath/issues/43))

Comment: It's a shame that the "Author of Mastering Selenium WebDriver" states that `.//` and `//` in Selenium mean the same thing

Comment: From an XPath point of view they don't, from a Selenium point of view they do because the default fallback is a JavaScript XPath library that is not fully standards compliant.  If you use `.//` it may work sometimes, but it will not work all the time.

Comment: It's a double shame that the "core contributor the the JMeter Maven Plugin" doesn't actually know how Selenium works. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56099974/2897748

Comment: Unfortunately there are an awful lot of half-baked tutorials on XPath in Selenium so it is very hard to discover the truth, but I strongly suspect this statement is inaccurate. Remember that leading `//` and `.//` do mean the same thing if the context item is the root node of the document, which at the top level (that is, outwith a predicate) will generally be true in Selenium.

Comment: Selenium uses wicked good XPath as a fallback (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/atoms/locators/xpath.js#L44). Wicked good XPath is not a fully compliant XPath implementation https://github.com/google/wicked-good-xpath/issues/43. @DmitriT Please check your facts

Comment: This could be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606708/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-xpath

Answer (score 1):

1. `.//` - relative selection of all nodes matching the expression
2. `//`  - absolute selection of all nodes matching the expression
3. `./`  - is not a valid XPath expression
4. `/`   - selects root node of the document

More information:

- [XPath Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=40044727)
- [XPath 1.0 Language Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/)

Comment: I agree your XPath is correct from a standards point of view, however XPath in Selenium is not 100% standards compliant which is what causes a lot of confusion.  This question is asking about using XPath with Selenium, not in a standards compliant way.

Comment: It's the matter of context, if you use `driver::findElementByXpath` - there is no difference between absolute and relative locators, however **there is the difference** when you use `webElement::findElementsByXpath`

Comment: You don't seem to understand what I'm saying.  Wicked Good XPath is broken!  If Selenium uses it to try and parse // it doesn't treat it as a synonym of ::descendant-or-self, instead it treats it as a wildcard search across the DOM.  This means that the relative node you supply before the // is irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

**Meaning of dot (.) in xpath :**

- Single Dot (.) - It points to current element.
- Double Dot (..) - It points to parent element.

**Meaning of '/' single slash and '//' double slash :**

- Single slash '/' - It search for child element.
- Double slash '//' :
  It search for child element as well as child's child element. In short it work as descendant.
- '//' it is a macro , it's expansion is : /descendant-or-self::node()/

**Answer to question :**

- //  - Search descendant or self node  in DOM
- .// - Search descendant or self node with respective to the current node
- /   - Search child node
- ./  - Search child node with respective to the current node

> For more information refer :
>   https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/basics-xpath-pritam-maske/